# Job ads with ridiculously wide salary ranges

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs

I see more and more job ads with ridiculously wide salary ranges, for example €40,000 - €150,000. I can't imagine that a company really has salary ranges so wide for a single position. It looks like companies only do this to attract more clicks. Maybe it's a good idea to limit salary ranges so that the maximum can't be higher than about 150% of the minimum?

Another explanation is that companies do have a more narrow salary range that they simply don't want to disclose. Anyway, such ranges aren't helpful for job seekers but they make the ads stand out more for no good reason.

Comment: Two things:  that *could* be a currency misrepresentation - salaries are frequently in the range of $40K-$100K in the states - or it could genuinely be the case that the company *is* offering that.

Comment: It probably means „We’ll pay you between €100k and €150k unless we can find someone from elsewhere in the world who’s happy working remotely for a third of that.“ Those salary ranges seem to coincide a lot with „remote“ labels

Comment: They might have their positions less granular, like "software developer" is a position that encompasses everything from juniors all the way through to leads...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Shouldn't companies post separate ads for junior and senior positions then?

Comment: Same kind of problem as asking SO users to disclose their age when they create an account.  They just enter nonsense if they don't want to, lots of 92 year old users around.  So just read it for what it looks like, they don't want to tell you.

Comment: @HansPassant - If users are supposed to have the ability to filter out jobs without salary info then this behavior breaks that feature. A fix could be allowing users to filter out jobs based on a salary range but I don't know if that's something they'd be willing to work on.

Comment: *Shouldn't companies post separate ads for junior and senior positions then?* That only works (for them) if they're trying to fill two or more roles. If they're just looking to hire one person and are flexible with experience level (willing to train a junior dev but have the budget to pay a senior one) it makes more sense (for them) to have only one posting but with the wide salary range. But you should see a wide experience range too, if that's the case.

Comment: Better yet: don't change anything and use it as an indicator you should stay far away.

Answer (score 3):

It can be fake jobs advertising in order to do job market survey. Before hiring for some position, companies can make a market survey in order to evaluate the pool of candidates, their skills and the salary they expect. And after the survey is finished they can make a real job add or directly contact candidate from the pool.

Some HeadHunter agency also do this in order to spy :

1. The company A wants to know how it's competitor (company B) works
   since it's has better profit.
2. The company A hire a Headhunting company to spy.
3. The Headhunting company will post an (fake) add, an 
   then call people of company B to say they have a great (fake)
   oppotunity, and durind the phone call the Headhunting company will
   ask informations ( such has : name of other people who works in
   company B, name of the differents departements, what are the client,
   what are the suppliers, etc).
4. Finally the Headhunting company will get money for diving information about company B to company A.

Comment: This does sound not-very-intelligent, and relying on the non-smarts of not-very-intelligent people. Who would reveal anything about his current employer or colleagues to a headhunter? Is that even legal?

Comment: They reveal something if the caller has talent, knows how to make people talk by making promise about a fake job.